# Why doesn't apt-get install the latest version of libstdc++6?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have a problem where the installation associated with apt-get is a different version than conda, causing problems when loading python packages.

```
sudo find / -name "libstdc++.so*"

/opt/conda/lib/libstdc++.so
/opt/conda/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/opt/conda/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
```

I can fix this by manually copying the files from /opt/conda/lib to /usr/lib/. However, I believe the recommended solution is to install the latest version of the package with apt-get.

This is what I get when doing that:

```
sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6

Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                    
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version (10.2.1-6).
Reading package lists... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

There are other recommended workarounds in https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/issues/13 such as adding a repository. I've tried all of them and nothing worked except manually copying over the files.

My question is why can't my apt install version 6.0.30, given that these files exist and were found by conda somehow? Is this an issue where the publishers of this dependency forgot to upload the latest version to the debian repositories that apt looks in?